# Regular Expression: brackets inside Square brackets

Tags: regex

I would like to match the following string:

```
[-ed, -ing, -ment <i>n.</i>]
```

But exclude:

```
[-ed, -ing, -ment <b>n.</b>]
```

And my regex is:

```
   \[[\-,\s\.(<i>)(</i>)a-z]+\]
```

Which won't work.

I add brackets to `<i>` so it appears as a whole, so `<b>` wont be matched.

However, brackets inside square brackets don't seem to work.

Comment: How do you think that regex works? Escaping the square brackets means they'll match literal square brackets, so how is `\-,(<i>)(</i>)a-z` supposed to match `-ed, -ing, -ment <i>n.</i>`?!

Comment: I noticed that problem you mentioned and rectified it. But `\[[\-,(<i>)(</i>)a-z]+\]` wont work either.

Comment: (After an edit.) Now you're just misunderstanding character classes (`[...]`). `[\-,(<i>)(</i>)a-z]` is equivalent to `[<>,\/()aiz-]`. May I suggest you read a regex tutorial?

Comment: Are you sure? `a-z` means any alphabet  from a to z, that is `a, b, c, d...z`

Comment: Ooops, my bad. It should be `[<>,\/()a-z-]`. It matches `<b>` because `<`, `b` and `>` are all in there. ‘*I add brackets to `<i>` so it appears as a whole*‘, that's where you're wrong; you've simply added `<`, `>`, `/`, `(`, `)` and `i` to the class, most of them twice.

Comment: Yes, your right. my question is how to match someting as a whole inside a square bracet, if `()` is not the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works with the sample string:

```
\[([^<>]|<i>.*?<\/i>)+?\]
```

I.e. square brackets containing a number of things that are either a single character that is neither `<` nor `>`, or `<i>[...]</i>` with some content.

It will match the first string and not the second. The problem description however is quite vague, so the regex might need some tweaking. E.g:

- Is it *just* `<i>` or *anything but* `<b>`?
- Can the square brackets contain nested square brackets?
- Are the contents of the square brackets in fact comma-separated elements that must all begin with a hyphen?